# Compile with clang as if with g++

Tags: g++, clang, compatibility

Say you have a complex compilation call with `g++`:

```
g++ -c -Wall -Werror -I/usr/include... bla bla
```

and you want the very same call to output exactly the same with `clang`:

```
clang -c -Wall -Werror -I/usr/include... bla bla
```

Is there an option for `clang` to compile exactly like `g++`?

The problem is that in our project we get no warnings/errors with the `g++` call, but many warnings with the `clang` call.

It would be nice to have a switch which disables all default options of `clang` and just parses the actual call parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take a look to [Clang users manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html), [wikipedia Clang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) and to [LibTooling](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html). A good tutorial about using Clang API is [compiling code Clang](http://fdiv.net/2012/08/15/compiling-code-clang-api).